# How to match URLs but not in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have urls that maybe inside brackets like this:

```
[[!;;;;http://example.com/foo]some text]
```

how to match URL but not when they are in brackets like that, `some text` may also be the URL. I need to replace all URLs to be in that format.

So far I have regex that match URLs:

```
var url_re = /(\bhttps?:\/\/(?:(?:(?!&[^;]+;)|(?=&amp;))[^\s"'<>\]\[)])+\b)/gi;
```

Example input:

```
http://example.com/foo [[!;;;;http://example.com/foo]some text] http://example.com/foo
```

output:

```
[[!;;;;http://example.com/foo]http://example.com/foo] [[!;;;;http://example.com/foo]some text] [[!;;;;http://example.com/foo]http://example.com/foo]
```

Comment: Ok, you want to replace URLs outside of brackets with tagged links. However, your URLs can reside inside nested balanced brackets, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, and I updated the question with example input and output.

Comment: Can `some text` contain `[` or `]`? If no, use [`\b(https?:\/\/(?:(?:(?!&[^;]+;)|(?=&amp;))[^\s"'<>\][)])+)\b(?![^[\]]*])`](https://regex101.com/r/oM7kR7/1) and replace with `[[!;;;;$1]$1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a `(?![^[\]]*])` negative lookahead that will avoid matching the pattern before a closing `]` that is not preceded with any other `[` or `]`:

```
\b(https?:\/\/(?:(?:(?!&[^;]+;)|(?=&amp;))[^\s"'<>\][)])+)\b(?![^[\]]*])
```

and replace with `[[!;;;;$1]$1]`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM7kR7/1)

Another option is to match and capture all inside `[...[...]...]` and then use a callback inside `String.replace()` to handle each capture properly, but the above seems "cleaner" and more direct.